# Abnormal Output from program

Tags: c++

I have a program that should print out 2 lists like the one bellow, basically the same list but backwards, however it works the first time but then it prints some weird output which I Will show bellow as well.

```
0123456789
9876543210
```

however the actual output I get from my program is this:

[image: sample Output]

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code please, I am not sure why I am getting this output.

```
void createFile(){
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("TEST1.txt");
  for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
   myfile << x << "\n";
  }
  myfile.close();
}

void popArray(int array1[]){
  ifstream infile("TEST1.txt");

  int x;
  while(infile >> array1[x]){
    cout << array1[x];
  }

}

void reverseList(int array2[]){
  for(int x = 9; x > -1; x--){
    cout << setw(2) << array2[x];
  }
} 

void checkLists(int array1[], int array2[], int sizeOfArray){
  for(int x = array1[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
    for(int y = array2[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
        if(x == y)
            cout << "Palindrome" << endl;
        else{
            cout << "Not" << endl;
        }
    }
  }

} 


int main()
{
  int array1[10];
  int array2[10];

  createFile();
  popArray(array1);

  cout << "\n";

  reverseList(array1);

  cout << "\n";
  checkLists(array1, array2, 10);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code please" without seeing the code, no.

Comment: Would you ever go to a car mechanic without your car, tell him your car doesn't work, and expect him to know what the problem is? Please show us your code.

Comment: oops, I will add code in a se

Comment: I would recommend you try to execute that code by hand, on paper. Write down the values of the variables at each step. (Hint: The only bit that actually works is `createFile`.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem I think:

```
void popArray(int array1[]){
 ifstream infile("TEST1.txt");

 int x;
 while(infile >> array1[x]){
 cout << array1[x];
 }

}
```

You never specify what x is. If I understand what you're trying to do I think this should work:

```
void popArray(int array1[]){
 ifstream infile("TEST1.txt");

 int x;
 for (x=0; x < 10; x++){
  cout << array1[x];
 }

}
```

Just read through a bit more. You've also got errors here:

```
void checkLists(int array1[], int array2[], int sizeOfArray){
 for(int x = array1[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
 for(int y = array2[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
     if(x == y)
        cout << "Palindrome" << endl;
     else{
        cout << "Not" << endl;
    }
    }
   }

}
```

I'd do something like:

```
bool checkLists(int array1[], int array2[], int sizeOfArray){

bool isPalindrome=true;
for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){

    if(array1[x] != array2[sizeOfArray-(x+1)]){
        isPalindrome = false;
        }
 }

return isPalindrome;
}
```

Then at the end of `main` you could have:

```
if(checkLists(array1, array2, 10)){
 cout << "Is Palindrome\n";
}
else{
cout << "Is Not Palindrome\n";
}
```

While I'm at it I might as well fix this too:

```
void reverseList(int array2[]){
for(int x = 9; x > -1; x--){
 cout << setw(2) << array2[x];
}
}
```

Change this to:

```
void reverseList(int array1[], int array2[]){
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  array2[9-i] = array1[i];
}
}
```

I think if you put together all the bits of my answer you should more or less have something that works. I've not tested it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

```
void popArray(int array1[]){
ifstream infile("TEST1.txt");

    int x;
    while(infile >> array1[x]){
       cout << array1[x];
    }

}
```

You are not changing `x` in your loop (or initializing `x` at all!)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x = array1[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
    for(int y = array2[1]; x < sizeOfArray; x++){if(x == y)
        cout << "Palindrome" << endl;
    else{
        cout << "Not" << endl;
    }
}
```

i this you should replace you code by this one

```
 for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < sizeOfArray; y++){
if(array1[x]== array2[y])
            cout << "Palindrome" << endl;
        else{
            cout << "Not" << endl;
        }
    }
```